# VerticalScroller is not working inside Column widget

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

I am trying to embed VerticalScroller inside the column widget but scroll behavior is not working.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        Container(alignment = Alignment.TopCenter) {
            Column {
                Padding(padding = 16.dp) {
                    Text(text = "Names")
                }
                VerticalScroller {
                    Column(crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.Center) {
                        (1..100).forEach {
                            Padding(padding = 8.dp) {
                                Text(text = "Name $it")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For embedding `VerticalScroller` inside Column you need to use `FlexColumn` and then embed `VerticalScroller` inside `flexible` function. For "Name List" `Text` use `inflexible`

**What is FlexColumn?**

> A composable that places its children in a vertical sequence,
>   assigning children heights according to their flex weights.

To achieve scroll behavior you need to try below code

```
 Container(alignment = Alignment.TopCenter) {
        FlexColumn {
            inflexible {
                Padding(padding = 16.dp) {
                    Text(text = "Names List")
                }
            }
            flexible(flex = 1f) {
                VerticalScroller {
                    Column {
                        (1..100).forEach {
                            Padding(padding = 8.dp) {
                                Text(text = "Name $it")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Check below gif
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For released version `1.0.0` you can use `verticalScroll` modifier:

```kotlin
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState)
) {
    Text("Test 1")
    Text("Test 2")
    Text("Test 3")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `1.0.0-beta02` you can use the [**`LazyColumn`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#lazycolumn).
Something like:

```
val items = listOf(0.100)
LazyColumn(items) { item ->
    Text(text = "Name $item")
}
```